# String to collection with empty String

Tags: java, string, collections, separator, stringtokenizer

I have the following String:

```
,Test1,,Test2
```

And want to put it into a Collection like this:

```
[],[Test1],[],[Test2]
```

My Code

```
    public static void stringToCollectionEmpty(String separator, String str, Collection col) {

    if (str != null) {
        StringTokenizer tok= new StringTokenizer(str, separator);
        String nextToken;
        while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            nextToken = tok.nextToken();
            if (nextToken != null && nextToken.trim().length() > 0) {
                col.add(nextToken.trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only get

```
[Test1],[Test2]
```

But I want to put also the given empty String before and between the comma into the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using functional programming:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ",Test1,,Test2";

    List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
            .map(t -> "[" + t + "]")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[], [Test1], [], [Test2]]
```

If you don't need the extra brackets around your `String`s you can instead just use:

```
List<String> collect = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
```

Comment: We can also have `t -> String.format("[%s]", t)` in place of `t -> "[" + t + "]"`

Comment: @Isank As far as I know, `String.format` is generally slower than simply using string concatenation. One aspect of it is that is has to parse the `format` which is something I would try to avoid in loop-like constructs.

Answer (score 2):

You have moved empty strings mannully by

```
if (nextToken != null && nextToken.trim().length() > 0) {
```

You might want this:

```
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nextToken = tok.nextToken();
        // if you need replace blank string with empty string, keep next line
        // nextToken = nextToken.trim()
        col.add(nextToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextToken.trim().length() > 0` is false for the empty strings, so they are not being added to the collection

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void stringToCollectionEmpty(String separator, String str, Collection col) {

if (str != null) {
    StringTokenizer tok= new StringTokenizer(str, separator);
    String nextToken;
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nextToken = tok.nextToken();
        if (nextToken != null && nextToken.trim().length() >= 0) {
            col.add(nextToken.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

}